# IntelliJ new-ed class files cannot be detected by git

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

These days, in my mac (EI Captain 10.11.6) IntelliJ (2017.2.6) I just encountered this weird thing.

Just created a new class: DumpVersionEnum

[image]

But I cannot add it and commit to my Github repository
[image]

I checked lots of posts and articles mentioned the solutions:

- Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Test button : it's working well;
- git command `git add *` in plain terminal : not working;
- right click the file -> Git (popup menu) -> Add (Option + Command + A) : it's grey (disabled) actually
- git clone the repo in another folder and then move the files in : not working either;

But the newly added classes just cannot be tracked and pushed to git.

Can any one help? Thank you ~

A workaround for now I achieved: move the files into the root folder of the project -> add -> commit and they are pushed to the remote repo but as mentioned, they cannot be tracked in the project package folder.

[image]

I also tried to then move them to the package in IntelliJ but then they will be again un-detected by the git. Even I do the moving in **plain terminal** or **mac Finder**.

**I tried the moving in a new folder (newly git cloned), just did not do**

[image]

Comment: Are you ignoring them by any chance? Not you, but git, say. Run **git status --ignored**

Comment: @eftshift0 It turned out that **I am** the one to blame. Accidentally **uncommented** a **#Java** comment in `.gitignore`. I think as you said `git status --ignored` actually can help. Thank you ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual possible causes are:

- those files are ignored: see if that is the case with:

  ```
  git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/file
  ```
- those files are part of

  - a nested Git repository (look for a .git in the parent folders)
  - a submodule (look for a .gitmodules in the root folder of your main repository)

Comment: Thank you, @VonC Via the `git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/file`, I found out there is a mis-added **Java** in my `.gitignore` at line 25. Problem finally solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hearen Great! What I like with `git check-ignore -v` is that it give you the exact path of the various `.gitignore` files involved.

Comment: Yes, VonC. Exactly,  that's the easiest and clearest way to find out what's happening for the **ignored**.